# Dedicating two identical mini-pets in different characters, under the same account

Tags: guild-wars

Will my HoM allow me to dedicate two of the same mini-pet to different characters under the same account and be accredited for each as a different point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not. You will need to have 50 unique minipets in order to completely fill the "Devotion" monument.

Comment: that's correct, to add to this answer, only the items that show up when you show your HoM for your entire account qualifies towards  accreditation